# Tess4j jar file issue

Tags: java, image, tess4j

```
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract;

public class Tess4JSample {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    URL imageURL = new URL("http://s4.postimg.org/e75hcme9p/IMG_20130507_190237.jpg");    
    RenderedImage img = ImageIO.read(imageURL);
    File outputfile = new File("saved.png");
    ImageIO.write(img, "png", outputfile);

    try {
    Tesseract instance = Tesseract.getInstance(); // JNA Interface Mapping

    //   Tesseract1 instance = new Tesseract1(); // JNA Direct Mapping

        String result = instance.doOCR(outputfile);
        System.out.println(result);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}
}
```

for this program I have put the jar files `tess4j-1.5.0` and `jai_imageio-1.1`. But still it shows `error`

```
The import net.sourceforge cannot be resolved
```

Can anyone tell me what is the necessary action needs to be taken care for error resolution? I taken this program from stack overflow itself. Thanks! in advance.

Comment: Where you added Jar file?

Comment: Are you keeping these `.jar` files on the `classpath`, while executing?

Comment: I added the .jar files in project webcontent>webINF>lib folder in eclipse @SubodhJoshi

Comment: Is this `lib` folder in your classpath?

Comment: Kindly dnt feel bad. How can we check whether it is in classpath or not? @SubodhJoshi

Comment: Its ok @Sherin no issue Which IDE you are using if Eclipse then simply check `Right click on Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries` check if Jar available here or your `lib` folder exist here if not add it.

Comment: I have added the jar files in Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries . But issue still persists. @SubodhJoshi

Comment: Now Build your project again and test?

Comment: I tried to build project. But issue still there. How can I show screenshot here? I will show that to you so that you could be checking it. @SubodhJoshi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83962/discussion-between-subodh-joshi-and-sherin).

Comment: after creating a new java project also still have issue@SubodhJoshi

Comment: Can anyone suggest me the root cause of this issue. For this I have added tess4j-1.5.0 jar file in classpath. Any help is appreciable.Thanks!